# Does adblock prevent website elements from loading in the first place?

Tags: html, adblock

When a adblocker is running, can it prevent an offending element from loading in the first place?

Or does it have to download all parts of the website and just hide it?

Comment: It downloads all of the website resources *before* hiding it. Adblockers do not have access to the content of the site before it's downloaded, it wouldn't be able to hide elements before knowing what elements a page will contain.